# Tools to measure websocket performance

Tags: node.js, performance, azure, websocket, socket.io

Hosting with Azure, an Ubuntu 12.04 instance running node.js and socket.io. What tools or methods are available to me for measuring websocket performance. In particular, I am most interested in understanding the maximum number of connections I can reasonably support.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.neotys.com/blog/load-performance-testing-websocket-technology/
Its a good commercial tool for testing WebSocket performance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool of Open Source named `tcpkali` on GitHub, please see https://github.com/machinezone/tcpkali.

You can enable the websocket option via `--ws` or `--websocket`, then specify the connection number and the interval time of sending messages for it, and send stats to [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/) or [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/) to help analysising performance.